# I have tried to update data into database in this way but something maybe not working for the first if statement where if ( !empty($_POST) )

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, pdo

I have tried to update data into database in this way but something maybe not working for the first if statement where if ( !empty($_POST) )
Please see this image to understand clearly

```
<?php   require_once '../App/start.php';  if ( !empty($_POST) ) {   $id     = $_POST['id'];     $label  = $_POST['label'];  $title  = $_POST['title'];  $slug   = $_POST['slug'];   $body   = $_POST['body'];   $updatePage = $db->prepare("UPDATE pages SET label=:label, title=:title,body =:body, slug=:slug, updated=NOW() WHERE id = :id");    $updatePage->execute([      'id'        => $id,         'label'     => $label,      'title'     => $title,      'body'      => $body,       'slug'      => $slug    ]);     header('Location:' . BASE_URL . '/index.php'); }  if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {    header('Location:' . BASE_URL . '/Admin/list.php');     die(); }  $edit = $db->prepare("SELECT id, label, title, body, slug FROM pages WHERE id = :id"); $edit->execute(['id' => $_GET['id']]); $edits = $edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/Admin/edit.php';
```

From this code first statement does not working to update data to database

Comment: Please format code using the `{}` button. Do you get any errors? Are you checking for them?

Comment: Thats how to format your code so we can actually read it

Comment: Urrmmmm You seem to be using `$_POST` and `$_GET` which are you actually using. Show us your `<form...>` tag or the `<a ....>` tag you are using to run this script

Comment: Anybody out there?????? Or was that you issue????

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xaoGU.png | http://i.stack.imgur.com/0TmGC.png this the form and code!

Comment: Please dont post links to images. copy/paste the code into your question

Comment: I formatted your code ONCE ALREADY. This time YOU FORMAT YOUR CODE

Answer (score 0):

You should test post like following if you want to check method and values.

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset ($_POST ['id']))`

Otherwise `if ( isset ($_POST ['id']) )` is enough.

Comment: `var_dump ($_POST)`  before first if statement. What is the result?

Comment: Ohh, Its an empty array()

Comment: So debug the form or post it here if you want help!